# Big-Oh ascending order of some functions f(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Put these function in the ascending order of their growth in terms of n:
 2^((log n)^0.5), 2^n, 2^(n/2), n^(4/3), n(log n)^3, n^(log n), 2^(n^2), n!

Comment: This is not a homework service.

Answer (score 0):

The way you solve this problem is by seeing which function approaches infinity fastest as `n` approaches infinity. Suppose you have some functions:

```
f(n) = n!
g(n) = n
h(n) = 3^n
```

You can compare any two functions by evaluating their ratio as `n` approaches infinity. For example:

```
Lim      f(n) /
n->∞         / g(n)
```

If the result is greater than 1, then `f(n)` is asymptotically greater than `g(n)`. If the result is 1, then they are asymptotically the same. If the result is less than one, then `f(n)` is asymptotically less than `g(n)`.

You may find that some are easy to solve, like `f(n)` and `g(n)`, and you can simplify the expression to get a definite value at the limit.

```
    f(n) /       = n! /    = n (n-1)! /   = (n-1)!
        / g(n)       / n             / n
```

The limit as `n` goes to infinity of this expression is infinity, which means that `f(n)` is asymptotically greater than `g(n)`.

Other expressions are not as simple. If evaluating the limit gives you an indeterminite form, you need to use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

```
Lim      g(n) /        =  Lim    n /     =  ∞ /
n->∞         / h(n)       n->∞    / 3^n      / ∞
```

According to L'Hôpital's rule, we can evaluate a limit by substituting `g'(n)` and `h'(n)`.

```
Lim      g'(n) /         =  Lim    1 /           =  1 /
n->∞          / h'(n)       n->∞    / 3^n ln(3)      / ∞
```

This limit is clearly less than 1, so we can say that `g(n)` is asymptotically less than `h(n)`.

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer: 2^((log n)^0.5), 2^(n/2), 2^n, n!, 2^(n^2).

Need to put these as well: n^(4/3), n(log n)^3, n^(log n)